# Distinguishing between a nucleophilic substitution and an electrophilic substitution

Tags: organic-chemistry, nucleophilic-substitution, electrophilic-substitution

Why don't we consider all nucleophilic substitution reactions as electrophilic reactions and vice versa?

For example, look at this reaction I found in my textbook. (See picture)

[image: Reaction forming chloropicrin]

This is an electrophilic substitution if we consider the H+ to be replaced by NO2+.

But if we look at it as the OH- ion being replaced by a CCl3- ion, then it can also be a nucleophilic substitution reaction! I'm so confused!

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It depends on if it is **initiated** by a attack from an electophile or a nucleophile.

Comment: It seems to me that your textbook failed here. That isn't a simple substitution.

Comment: @Akari how do we deduce which attacks first?

Comment: See the mechanism of the concerned reaction

Comment: @Akari does it have anything to do with the nitric acid being concentrated?

Comment: @Akari Well the mechanisms exactly what I'm looking for. Can't find it anywhere